# Disable Form on Submission Javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a form that will submit multiple times if clicked more than once. I want to disable the form from being submited mutliple times.

Heres the button:

```
 <a style="float:right" onclick="javascript:document.forms['form1'].submit();" class="button"><span><bean:message key="common.continue"/></span></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty without changing much code**

Just change the html part to:

```
<a style="float:right" onclick="javascript:document.forms['form1'].submit();this.disabled=true;" class="button"><span><bean:message key="common.continue"/></span></a>
```

Comment: The click event will still fire and will submit the form again. It's an anchor tag not input or button

Comment: It's cool. Either edit the post to give suitable answer or delete it. Better than getting downvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Call a funtion when you submit the form instead of inline js.

### HTML

```
 <a style="float:right" onclick="myFunction()" class="button"><span><bean:message key="common.continue"/></span></a>
```

### Javascript

```
    var submitForm = true; //For first time submission
    function myFunction(){
        if(submitForm){
            submitForm = false; //do not allow it to be submitted again
            document.forms['form1'].submit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about security, the verification must be done server side. Javascript protection can be easily bypassed.
If you have access to the server code, you can check in a databsase if the exact same information the client is sending, already exists.

Otherwise you should combine both methods, disabling the html button and setting a variable to remember that the form as already been sent.